# Is there a way to remove the hash from combined javascript files in SquishIt?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, squishit

I'm using [SquishIt](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt) to combine and minify my javascript files in an MVC 3 project.  I'm trying to create an offline cache.manifest and the hash codes changing between edits is killing me.  Is there a way to remove the hash that is appended to the bundle?

I checked in the [BundleBase.cs](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/blob/master/SquishIt.Framework/Base/BundleBase.cs) class and see a `HashKeyNamed` method but can't figure out where I would use it.

Here is my existing method for combining:

```
@Html.Raw(SquishIt.Framework.Bundle.JavaScript()
.Add("~/js/libs/persistence.js")
.Add("~/js/offline.common.js")
.Add("~/js/offline.syncmanager.js")
// snip...
.ForceRelease()    
.WithMinifier(SquishIt.Framework.JavaScript.Minifiers.JavaScriptMinifiers.NullMinifier)    
.Render("~/js/offline_script.js"))
```

Comment: The method you mention was probably intended to be added to the interface, though I can't say for sure.  I suspect you'd be better off with a method to allow excluding the querystring hash from rendered filenames (not just rename it).  I would recommend opening an issue on github for this - your use case for bypassing cache invalidation seems reasonable enough, and I can see this change being useful to others.

Comment: @AlexCuse Thanks.  The reason I mentioned the HashKeyNamed property is because if you set it to null I notice the render method will bypass adding it to the URL.

Comment: Ah, ok.  We could probably use that behind the scenes but I think a 'WithoutHash' method might make more sense.  Since this will cripple normal browser caching I think its best to be as explicit as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I'm late to the party.

In the latest version, there is a method on bundles called .WithoutRevisionHash() that will do what you needed.  This method actual came into being thanks to [Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133701/jacob)'s pull request mentioned here.

The method itself is just a wrapper for a previously existing method called .HashKeyNamed() that could be called with an empty string as he pointed out to accomplish the result you're after.  Hopefully the new method is a bit more intuitive/discoverable though :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way. You can see all the public API options here: https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/blob/master/SquishIt.Framework/Base/IBundle.cs

It is OSS though, so you can always fork the project and make the addition!

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently [submitted a pull](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt/pull/158) for some better support of this in [SquishIt](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt), but in the mean time, I think you can pull this off by creating your own custom `JavaScriptBundle` and using the `HashKeyNamed()` method.

```
public class NoHashJavaScriptBundle : JavaScriptBundle
{
    public NoHashJavaScriptBundle()
        : base()
    { }

    protected override string BeforeMinify(string outputFile, List<string> files, IEnumerable<string> arbitraryContent)
    {
        // Set the hash key to empty to keep it from being appended in Render.
        HashKeyNamed(string.Empty);

        return base.BeforeMinify(outputFile, files, arbitraryContent);
    }
}
```

Then in your `_Layout` you could do something like this:

```
@Html.Raw(new NoHashJavaScriptBundle()
.Add("~/js/libs/persistence.js")
.Add("~/js/offline.common.js")
.Add("~/js/offline.syncmanager.js")
// snip...
.ForceRelease()    
.WithMinifier(SquishIt.Framework.JavaScript.Minifiers.JavaScriptMinifiers.NullMinifier)    
.Render("~/js/DontHashMeBro.js"))
```